# Task completes before notifying progress. Why and how to fix?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

So I'm trying to use task progress notification using `IProgress<T>`. Here is what I do:

1. Create a `Progress<T>` and attach a handler to its `ProgressChanged` event.
2. In the event handler, I update UI-specific property to show progress.
3. Run a loop and create `Task` objects to do units of work. Each Task uses `Progress` object to report progress (which will in turn invoke `ProgressChanged` and update UI).
4. Use `Task.WaitAll()` to block till all tasks have finished. Show a completion message at the end.

The code looks something like this:

```
IProgress<Tuple<DataRow, MyVM>> BakeProgress;
BakeProgress = new Progress<Tuple<DataRow, MyVM>>();

((Progress<Tuple<DataRow, MyVM>>)BakeProgress).ProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
  _BakeProgress += 100.0 / AllDataRows.Length;
  RaisePropertyChanged(NameOf(BakeProgress));
};

var BakeTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var dr in AllDataRows) {

  BakeTasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
  {
    var Baked = MyBakingFunc();

    BakeProgress.Report(new Tuple<DataRow, MyVM>(dr, Baked));

    return Baked;
  }));
}

Task.WaitAll(BakeTasks.ToArray());      //Shouldn't this wait

MessageBox.Show("Baking Completed");
```

To my surprise, this code hits `MessageBox` line **before** hitting `ProgressChanged` event handler even once. What am I doing wrong?

N.B. It DOES hit `ProgressChanged` event handler once for every Task instance, but only **after** hitting the Completed line.

N.B. Ah and I did read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699053/console-messages-appearing-in-incorrect-order-when-reporting-progress-with-iprog), but since this is WPF, we do have a synchronization context in which the `Progress` object was created.

Comment: Tip: You don't need `Task.Run`, and you should use `await Task.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WaitAll`.

Comment: Also, please use `camelCase` for locals and parameters, not `PascalCase`.

Comment: @Dai: Thanks. Why don't I need `Task.Run`? Are you suggesting I shouldn't multi-thread it?

Comment: As you read - progress handler will run on UI thread in your case. But your UI is blocked waiting for all tasks to complete. So only after all tasks are complete (and message box shown) - UI thread will be available to run progress handlers.

Comment: @Dai: I do use camelCase for parameters, but PascalCase for locals. Not sure exactly when I started following that style, but it does help me at times.

Comment: That depends if `MyBakingFunc` is IO-bound or not. If it's IO-bound then you don't need more threads, you can do async programming with a single thread. If it's CPU bound then yes, use `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Evk: aaaaaaaaaah...

Comment: @Dai: I see it now. And thanks, `WhenAll()` solves this issue. And no, my tasks are not IO-bound.