Progress reporting and Task continuation race conditions
I have a LogWriter class that accepts a file path and a System.Windows.Forms.TextBox and then writes to both in a public void Write(string progress) method. It uses a StreamWriter with AutoFlush to append to the file and, therefore, it itself implements IDisposable to dispose of the stream. It just sets the Text property on the text box each time.
I have a method in another class that spawns processes and uses event handlers on the ErrorDataReceived and OutputDataReceived events to call Report() on the Progess instance.
In an async button click event handler on the Form I do the following:
using(LogWriter logger = new LogWriter(filePath, txtProgress))
{
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s => logger.Write(s));
    await Task.Run(() => this._C.RunProcess(progress));
} //disposal point

Before that, I implemented it using a ContinueWith in a sync handler:
LogWriter logger = new LogWriter(filePath, txtProgress);
Task t = Task.Run(() => this._C.RunProcess(progress));
t.ContinueWith((_) => { coreCurrentLogger.Dispose(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

I understand that calling Progress.Report() uses SynchonizationContext.Post() to queue the lambda to be executed some time later. In this case, I believe the SynchonizationContext will be that of the UI Thread.
In both cases this code behaves as I expect. The TextBox and file both contain the final string written to the output stream by the spawned process.
Based on the above, is there a race condition in either implementation where the LogWriter instance could be disposed before all of the Process.Report() lambdas have been executed?
Is there a difference between the two implementations? Do I need a ConfigureAwait(true) on the first example?

I'd create the LogWriter object inside the method passed as the Action delegate called by Progress.Report(), instead of using a Lambda, and dispose of it there, which makes it ~similar to the second snippet -- Did you omit the part that sets the TextBox, for brevity, or... -- If that LogWriter object has other tasks in that context, add the detail

The LogWriter appends to a text file so I don't want to keep opening and closing the file with every call to Report(). I omitted the content of that class for brevity: the constructor opens a StreamWriter and stores a reference to the TextBox. The Write() method does``tb.Text = valueandsw.WriteLine(value)`.

So, it's a log writer that also does UI stuff. Peculiar. Anyway, what I wrote before is what I, personally, would do (besides using an actual Logging package, that is)

Yeah. It's just a "quick and dirty" to encapsulate the logic for writing to a text box for the user to see and writing the same string to a file. I need to do this half a dozen times (at the same time) and didn't want to C&P the same thing everywhere or reference a logging package. Thanks for your feedback.

"Do I need a ConfigureAwait(true) on the first example?" ConfigureAwait(true) is a no op.  Adding it to any code won't change its behavior ever.

I realised that I need the disposal to happen on the UI thread and ConfigureAwait(true) would make that happen. I forgot that would be the default behaviour and adding it would be a no-op (facepalm).

There is indeed a race condition here.  Progress Posts the handlers, rather than sending them, so the worker is permitted to continue execution before the progress reporting has actually taken place, meaning in theory it's possible for the entire operation to end with one or more progress reporting handlers running.
The Progress class itself provides no way to wait for all existing handlers to finish.
A solution is to wrap the Progress object in one that tracks the number of ongoing handlers and provides a Task to notify you when all ongoing handlers are complete.
public class TrackableProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    private IProgress<T> nestedProgress;
    private int handlersRunning = 0;
    private TaskCompletionSource? taskCompletionSource;
    public object key = new object();

    public TrackableProgress(Action<T> action)
    {
        nestedProgress = new Progress<T>(Handler);

        void Handler(T t)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (key)
                    handlersRunning++;

                action(t);
            }
            finally
            {
                lock (key)
                {
                    handlersRunning--;
                    if (handlersRunning == 0)
                    {
                        taskCompletionSource?.TrySetResult();
                        taskCompletionSource = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void IProgress<T>.Report(T value)
    {
        nestedProgress.Report(value);
    }
    public Task HandlersFinished()
    {
        Task? result = null;
        lock (key)
        {
            if (handlersRunning > 0)
            {
                taskCompletionSource ??= new TaskCompletionSource(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
                result = taskCompletionSource.Task;
            }
        }
        return result ?? Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

This will allow you to write:
using(LogWriter logger = new LogWriter(filePath, txtProgress))
{
    TrackableProgress<string> progress = new TrackableProgress<string>(s => logger.Write(s));
    await Task.Run(() => this._C.RunProcess(progress));
    await progress.HandlersFinished();
}


This is a good solution. +1 You could consider making the TrackableProgress<T> IAsyncDisposable, and moving the HandlersFinished functionality in the DisposeAsync method. It would make the usage of the class simpler, albeit a bit more cryptic.

You could also consider initializing the TaskCompletionSource with the TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously option, otherwise the continuation after the await progress.HandlersFinished(); might run inside the lock (key) section. This can happen if the await is configured with ConfigureAwait(false).

@TheodorZoulias Thanks, I forget about that option more than I should.

Tenuously related: does the SynchonizationContext being an instance of WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext guarantee that the Report() lambdas will run in the order they are enqueued? I.e. Does winforms suffer the same issue as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699053/

@TheodorZoulias would you please explain a bit more about why the continuation "might run inside the lock (key) section"? Is this related to re-ordering during optimisation?

Oh, because TrySetResult() is called inside the lock which could trigger the continuation to run right there?

​​@DanDef yes, the reason is the TrySetResult that is called inside the lock section. Something similar happens if you Cancel a CancellationTokenSource inside a lock section. The callbacks attached to the associated CancellationToken are invoked right there.


I understand that calling Progress.Report() uses SynchonizationContext.Post() to queue the lambda to be executed some time later. In this case, I believe the SynchonizationContext will be that of the UI Thread.

Correct.

Is there a race condition in either implementation where the LogWriter instance could be disposed before all of the Process.Report() lambdas have been executed?

Yes, both implementations suffer from this race condition. The Progress<T> class doesn't provide any notification mechanism regarding the completion of the asynchronous Report operations, so as long as you use this class race conditions are inevitable. You might be able to alleviate this race condition by adding a await Task.Yield(); after awaiting the Task.Run task, hoping that the underlying SynchonizationContext processes the scheduled operations in FIFO order. There is no guarantee about this though. It is theoretically possible that the Task.Yield awaitable will be completed with higher priority, bypassing existing scheduled Report operations.
If you want to be absolutely sure that there is no race condition in your code, you have no other option than to abandon the Progress<T> class, and use a custom IProgress<T> implementation. The simplest is to make the reporting synchronous instead of asynchronous. You can find a SynchronousProgress<T> here. The implication is that the background operation will be suspended each time a Report is issued, so it will become slightly slower. As long as the Report is issued infrequently, the performance impact will not be significant enough to be noticeable.

Making the progress synchronous comes at the cost of slowing down the underlying operation, potentially significantly.  And if the underlying operation is asynchronous and calls Report on the current synchronization context (expecting it to not block), it could even result in deadlocks.  By having the handlers simply track how many are running, rather than making them all block Report you can enable a way to wait for all handlers currently running (which is likely to be few) only at the very end.

@Servy sure, reporting synchronously is not ideal, but it's the simplest solution to this problem. If I had this problem, that's what I would do at first, and I would search for a more sophisticated alternative only if the performance impact proved to be anything but negligible.

The risk of deadlocks is particularly concerning, even if you can ignore performance, especially because it could become a problem in the future due to changes in the underlying operation that is unlikely to be aware or considering the implementation details of the progress reporting.  That and it's just also fairly common for progress reporting to happen often enough that I'd expect it to be a concern.

Another concern with blocking is that if the UI thread is being blocked/heavily used by unrelated processes, it slows down the actual work and not just the UI reporting.  This is another case where the performance impact may be negligible in initial testing, but become a problem due to changes to [potentially] unrelated parts of the system.  The performance of this operation suddenly has become dependent on the entirety of the UI.

@Servy reporting synchronously certainly opens deadlock scenarios, thanks for pointing it out. I wouldn't call it particularly concerning though, because if a deadlock happens it will be noticed right away, during the development of the application. This is true for typical sync over async deadlocks as well. They make their presence extremely loud. They are highly unlikely to slip into production code. The developer is literally forced to fix the problem immediately, using any of the various workarounds available.

Unless the behavior is conditional.  For example, if the first awaited task uses ConfigureAwait, but only rarely returns a completed task, or progress reporting is conditional and only rarely occurs before the first awaited task with ConfigureAwait(false).  But yes, in common situations it would be noticed immediately.  But removing the risk is easy enough that I would consider it worth doing.  Particularly if this progress reporting method is something the OP uses in a lot of places.

@Servy personally I am a fan of synchronous reporting for three reasons: 1. it exposes the common mistake of reporting too frequently. 2. It exposes incorrectly written code that blocks the UI thread for no reason. 3. It's very simple. The 1st is particularly common. I've seen too many people flooding the UI scheduler by calling Report a million times in a loop, and then wonder why the UI is not responding. Reporting synchronously forces the developer to Report conservatively, otherwise the operation takes forever (but the UI remains responsive).

I prefer to solve the problem directly, rather than indirectly.  Have something that specifically tracks how responsive the UI is and logs long running UI messages or excessive queue lengths.  That and blocking the UI thread or flooding it with messages is typically visible when testing even without synchronous progress reporting.  People just ignore it.

@Servy an alternative to synchronous reporting that doesn't suffer from the problems of the Progress<T>, could be a class that schedules no more than one asynchronous operation. In case the Report is called again before the previous pending operation is started on the UI thread, the old T of the pending operation would be swapped with the new T, without launching an additional asynchronous operation. The result would be more accurate progress reporting under heavy UI load, and more forgiving behavior in case of Report abuse.

That wouldn't help OP, as they're specifically logging all of the information, and so skipping any of it isn't acceptable (at most they could be batched and a single UI refresh could include information from numerous progress reports) but it's certainly appropriate in lots of contexts unrelated to this question, yes.

@Servy sorry, I forgot to add that this hypothetical IProgress<T> implementation would incorporate the notification mechanism of your TrackableProgress<T> class. Basically it would be a BoundedTrackableProgress<T>, with a bounded capacity of 1.
